# daily dynamic cron task to compress log files

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I would like to run a cron task every day at 01:00 every day.  The command would zip up log files from the day before.
This is for centos6 and centos7

This command line works, now I would like make this work as a daily dynamic cron task.

```
tar -zcvf ISP.June-22-2020.tar.gz ISP.2020-Jun22* --remove-files
```

I have been building on the idea of a data variable, using mtime.
The idea is find all files with day -1 that have "for" in the filename then zip them up into a compressed file based on the day.

```
#/bin/bash
now="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
find . -mtime -1 | grep -w for | xargs tar -zcvf ISP.${now}.tar.gz --remove-files
```

Thoughts, any improvement ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't logrotate what everyone use for this kinda things?

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to zip log files from the day before (i.e. yesterday),
then just look for files with names that contain $yesterday, where yesterday
is defined as follows:

```
yesterday="$(date -d yesterday +'%Y-%m-%d')"
```